# Linux C: How to know the default interface for internet access?

Tags: c, linux, routes, ip, default

I want to find out the default network in use. My current method was to find all IP addresses and compare it to the default gateway IP address, but that sounds silly. What is the correct way of doing it ?

**UPDATE**

I want to use a C program, not by commands ...

Comment: Did you figure out something?

Answer (score 4):

You can try a slightly dirtier but infinitely easier approach:

```
cnicutar@lemon:~$ ip route show to 0.0.0.0/0
default via X.Y.Z.T dev eth0  proto static
                        ^^^^
```

So you can try:

```
FILE *cmd = popen("ip route show", "r");
fgets(str, LEN, cmd);
```

Then you can use `strtok`, `strstr` etc.

Comment: When I want to do something in code that a command already does, I normally seek out that command's source to see how it was already done. In this specific case, it might be by reading /proc (which the OP wants to avoid), or it might be through some ioctl() whose easiest found documentation is in that command's source.

Comment: @mah That's the right thing to do. However generally there's no easy way (ioctl, reading proc, netlink sockets etc) to do what `ip` does. It all gets pretty hairy pretty fast. So why not go with the flow and just use it until it proves to be too much of a problem.

Comment: Don't bother reading source code, just run the command under `strace` and see what system calls it makes. Everything else is just internal details. :)

Comment: @MikePennington I'm not. I expect it to be the available space in `str`.

Comment: @cnicutar, perhaps `sizeof str` is better than `LEN`?

Comment: @MikePennington Perhaps, but then what if `str` is not a true array but a pointer ?